# Which table save original price and promotional sale price in Magento 1.8.1?

Tags: mysql, magento-1.8

In **Magento 1.8.1**:
Which database table saves the original price and promotional sale price?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the table `catalog_product_index_price` the prices should be found there.

Comment: hi Kreshnik Hasanaj thanks for advance how to call original price and cell price sku wise